# Due to css tree, can't add or remove class. Everything in JQuery{click and hover)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to hover over an item, css changes, hover off, returns back to normal, select the item, css changes as well. When I select it again it returns back to normal. Or when I select another one of the items in the same line.

HTML

```
 <div class="body2">
                    <div class="block" id='block'>
                        <div class="block-header">
                            <div class="arrow-down" style="left:83px"></div>

                        </div>
                    <div class="block-body">
                        <p style="margin-top:25px;"></p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="block" id='block'>
                        <div class="block-header">
                            <div class="arrow-down" style="left:284px"></div>

                        </div>
                    <div class="block-body">

                        </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="block" id='block'>
                        <div class="block-header">
                            <div class="arrow-down" style="left:485px"></div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="block-body">

                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="block" id='block' style="margin-right:0px;">
                        <div class="block-header">
                            <div class="arrow-down" style="left:686px"></div>

                        </div>
                    <div class="block-body">

                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

CSS

```
.body2 .block{
display:inline-block;
border:solid 2px #eaeaea;
height: 165px;
width: 180px;
margin-right: 19px;
}
.body2 .block:hover{
cursor:pointer
}
.body2 .block .block-header{
    height: 35px;
border-bottom: solid 2px #eaeaea;
width: 180px;
}
.body2 .block .block-header .arrow-down{
 width: 15px;
height: 15px;
border: 2px solid #eaeaea;
transform: rotate(45deg);
border-top: 0;
border-left: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 10%;
background-color: #fff;
z-index: 10;
top: 74px;
 }

.body2 .block .block-body{
width:174px;
 }
```

JS

```
$('.body2 #block').hover(function(e){
    $($(e.currentTarget).find('.block-header')).css('border-color','blue');
    $($(e.currentTarget).find('.block-header')).css('background-color','blue');
    $($(e.currentTarget).find('.arrow-down')).css('background-color','blue');
    $($(e.currentTarget).find('.arrow-down')).css('border-color','blue');
    $(e.currentTarget).css('border-color','blue');
}, function(){
    $('.body2 .block .block-header').css('border-color','blue');
    $('.body2 .block .block-header').css('background-color','blue');
    $('.body2 .block .block-header .arrow-down').css('background-color','blue');
    $('.body2 .block .block-header .arrow-down').css('border-color','blue');
    $('.body2 .block').css('border-color','blue');
} );
```

On my local machine I am able to make it hover in and out, however I am not able to make the click selection. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/op4fLwbo/5/) it does not function. But as you can see, that is how it is displayed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a fiddle with the solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/op4fLwbo/14/

The js now looks like:

```
$('.body2 .block').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.block-header').toggleClass('hovered');
    $(this).find('.arrow-down').toggleClass('hovered');
    $(this).toggleClass('border-hover');
});
```

I have updated the js and the css. Why was not working on fiddle is beacause you were missing jquery.

Notw, on the css i have added important to the new classes added, because of the specificity of the css, which you need to fix.

Hope that helps you and it is what you needed.